# verticaly align text with larger bullets in a list

Tags: html, css, list, vertical-alignment

How can I align my text vertically. I found similar questions, but none of them solves my problem.

Heres the HTML:

```
<ul id="main_navi">
   <li class="main_navi">
      <a class="main_navi_link" href="#">nav_1</a>
   </li>
   <li class="main_navi">
      <a class="main_navi_link" href="#">nav_2</a>
   </li>
   <li class="main_navi">
      <a class="main_navi_link" href="#">nav_3</a>
   </li>                                 
</ul>
```

and the concerning css:

```
ul#main_navi li:nth-child(1){
    list-style-image:url(../pics/main_edit_folder_area.png);
}
ul#main_navi li:nth-child(2){
    list-style-image:url(../pics/main_search_data_area.png);
}

ul#main_navi li:nth-child(3){
    list-style-image:url(../pics/main_admin_area.png);
}

li.main_navi{
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The `vertical-align: middle;` does not help me here. When I use `display: block` for the `li.main_navi` the bullet-images disapear. 
Here you have an image:

[image: Thats how it actually looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgJBp/)**

**css**

```
ul#main_navi li{
list-style-type:none;
}
ul#main_navi li:nth-child(1){
    background-image:url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/pencil-48.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    background-position:-2px 10px;
    padding:0 0 0 50px;


}
ul#main_navi li:nth-child(2){
    list-style-image:url(../pics/main_search_data_area.png);
}

ul#main_navi li:nth-child(3){
    list-style-image:url(../pics/main_admin_area.png);

}

li.main_navi{
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: that one worked nice. Thanks. There are any disadvantages using background-images instead of having bullet-images?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the images which you are using cannot be vertically aligned using `vertical-align: middle;`, so use `background-image` with the `padding` set to `li` element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BNXp9/)

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul#main_navi li:nth-child(1){
   background:url(#); /* Add these properties here and get rid of list-style-image */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li.main_navi{
    line-height: 70px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 100px; /* Make sure you use this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
li.main_navi a{ line-height:70px; }
```

if not solve **add** or **subtract margin**..

Answer (score 0):

update your this css and try, I have just change the line-height to normal and changed the height to 70

```
li.main_navi {
height: 70px;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 200px;
```

}